# Usage of "no other" with "comparative" and "positive" degree

Tags: grammar

I have a question regarding **no other**. I have given two examples using **no other**. One in comparative degree and the other in positive degree.

Here are the examples:

1- **No other** poet in the world is more renowned than William Wordsworth.

I think I shouldn't use **no other** in sentences using comparative degree. I should use **No** because **no other** here means "William Wordsworth is more renowned than William Wordsworth." Am i right? But I have seen people use **no other**  and **no** interchangeably in this case?

2- **No other** poet in the world is as renowned as William Wordsworth.

I think If I use positive degree both **no other** and **no** seems natural. What do you think?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of those sentences could be formed without **other**.

> No man is faster than he is.
>
> No man is as fast as he is.

Although some native speakers would use **other** there it is unnecessary, and even a little jarring on a semantic level; in the following pattern, however, it is less jarring, though still unnecessary:

> No other man is faster than he is but Usain Bolt.

Only Usain Bolt is faster than he is.

> No other man is as fast as he is but Usain Bolt.

Only Usain bolt is as fast as he is.

Answer (score 1):

Both your examples are correct but they don't mean the same thing.

To say:

> No other poet in the world is more renowned than William Wordsworth.

means that other poets may be **as renouned** but they are not **more renouned**.

So, if you were to attribute the figure of 100 to Wordsworth's renoun, other poets would achieve a score of either 100 or less than 100.

On the other hand, so say:

> No other poet in the world is as renowned as William Wordsworth.

means that all other poets are **less renouned**.

All other poets achieve a figure of less than 100.

Comment: In practice that specific distinction (whether any other poets might be ***equally*** renowned) wouldn't normally occur to either the speaker or his audience - except in contexts such as answering this ELL question, where we're effectively being "artificially" encouraged to assume there ***must*** be at least some possibility of there being different meanings.

Comment: No one is a sure as I am about this answer. No one is more sure than I am about this answer. [the second one is false only because I don't know who else is sure, though if we were altogether in the same place discussing this, it could be true.